# ARMA_NO_DEBUG in R package with RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I want to disable bound checks when accessing to matrix elements in RcppArmadillo.

The documentations of Armadillo says

> Armadillo can be configured via editing the file
>   include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp. Specific functionality can be
>   enabled or disabled by uncommenting or commenting out a particular
>   #define, listed below.

But in the context of an R package, how can I activate this directive?

I have tried to create a `config.h`  file with

```
#ifndef CONFIG_LOADED
#define CONFIG_LOADED
#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG
#endif
```

and then including it in *every* .cpp file of my `/src` folder, but I'm not sure whether it works properly or whether there is some other way other than adding a `#include "config.h"`in each .cpp file.

---

Currently I have one .cpp (the one that contains the main algorithm) that start with:

```
#include "configs.h"
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP sample_gibbs_cpp(const arma::vec& v_n, const arma::mat& W, 
arma::vec h_n, double alpha = 1, double beta = 1, int iter=100,
double burnin = 0.5){
... code ...
}
```

And then others that are just

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
... code ...
```

My DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: mypackage
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends:
    R (>= 3.2.3)
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
Imports:
    ggplot2,
    dplyr,
    tidyr,
    rstan
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen
SystemRequirements: C++11
```

And I compile my package with:

```
devtools::load_all()
```

Comment: Post code for your package... In particular, how and when are you calling this header? Order matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order matters here. This `#define` statement must be included *before* the inclusion of `#include<RcppArmadillo.h>`

An example:

**custom_config.h**

```
#ifndef CONFIG_LOADED
#define CONFIG_LOADED
#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG
#endif
```

**example_compiled_file.cpp**

```
#include "custom_config.h"
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_pkg(const arma::vec& x) {

   // Should not trigger error bound checking with debug flag on.
   double my_val_protected = x(0);

   // Never triggers error bound checking
   double my_val = x.at(0);
}
```

**Note:** As this is a package, the use of `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` is not required. Instead, you must specify `RcppArmadillo` and `Rcpp` in the `LinkingTo:` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file as well as including `Rcpp` in the `Imports:` field. You will have to minimally import from `Rcpp` a function (preferably: `evalCpp`).

e.g. **DESCRIPTION** must have:

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.12.15)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
```

Comment: Thanks coatless. Is it mandatory to put RccpArmadillo in the Import: when it is already in LinkingTo: ? Do I need to add #include "custom_config.h" in each .cpp? I don't understand what you mean by minimally import, I just call them as if they where R functions from my R/example.R files.

Comment: @alberto whoops. Misspoke. `Rcpp` should be in `Import:` and `RcppArmadillo` should be included in `LinkingTo:` alongside `Rcpp`.

Comment: Oups, I had never put Rcpp in Import! (and RccpArmadillo worked anyway, although I have importFrom(Rcpp, sourceCpp) in my NAMESPACE file generated by roxygen2) -- So #include <RcppArmadillo.h> in the file where I want the optimization is enough?

Comment: This needs to come _after_ the `custom_config.h` include. Then, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant #include "custom_config.h" !

Comment: sure, but I'd just like to know whether #include custom_config.h goes in all .cpp files?

Comment: You must have `#include "custom_config.h"` in every `.cpp` that you want to the `#define` directives.